# Get the path of a JToken based on the parent name

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a Json file with multiple repetitions:

```
"flows": [
          {
            "network1": {
              "downlinkUnit": "u1Kbps",
              "downlinkValue": 2,
              "uplinkUnit": "u1Kbps",
              "uplinkValue": 10
            },
            "network2": {
              "downlinkUnit": "u2Kbps",
              "downlinkValue": 8,
              "uplinkUnit": "u4Kbps",
              "uplinkValue": 12
            },
           }
          ]
```

I am trying to access the 2 different `downlinkUnit` properties based on the value the parent has.
I think I am close to it, but there´s something I miss:

```
            var paramPath = jObject.Descendants()
                                   .OfType<JProperty>()
                                   .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("downlinkUnit") && p.Parent.Contains("network1"))
                                   .First()
                                   .Path;

            var token = jObject.SelectToken(paramPath);
            token.Replace(JToken.FromObject(item.Value));
            Console.WriteLine(paramPath);
```

If I remove `&& p.Parent.Contains("network1"))`, the code works fine and I can access the path for `downlinkUnit`. However, I do want something that checks the parent. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the value the parent has"? How do you want to "check" the parent (what exactly should be checked)?

Comment: @GuruStron By value of the parent I mean its name. I want to access the path of downlinkUnit under network1 or network2 depending on the value of the parent

Comment: What "value" are you talking about? Is your Json dynamic? Should only "network1" and "network2" be handled? Is it possible to have "network3"? Or you are afraid that there is some other "downlinkUnit" property in some completely other json object can be present?

Comment: @GuruStron I have a lot of parameters with the same name within this JSON file, so I´m accessing them giving a string (let´s say: "downlinkUnit_network1") and splitting it into "downlinkUnit" and "network1", so that I know exactly in which position they are in the JSON file, otherwise I  can´t access the "downlinkUnit" I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyze `Path` property of parent:

```
var paramPath = jObject.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("downlinkUnit") && p.Parent.Path.EndsWith(".network1"))
    .First()
    .Path;
```

Or use [JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
var x = @"{""flows"": [
          {
            ""network1"": {
              ""downlinkUnit"": ""u1Kbps"",
              ""downlinkValue"": 2,
              ""uplinkUnit"": ""u1Kbps"",
              ""uplinkValue"": 10
            },
            ""network2"": {
    ""downlinkUnit"": ""u2Kbps"",
              ""downlinkValue"": 8,
              ""uplinkUnit"": ""u4Kbps"",
              ""uplinkValue"": 12

            },
           }
          ]}";

var path = JToken.Parse(x)
    .SelectTokens("$.flows.[*].['network1'].downlinkUnit")
    .Select(t => t.Path)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine(path); // prints "flows[0].network1.downlinkUnit"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot! 
".EndsWith()" was the one thing was missing.

Comment: @DavideGanna Was glad to help! BTW you can just replace value of `JProperty` without extra path handling: `var paramPath = jObject....First(); paramPath.Value.Replace(JToken.FromObject(item.Value));`